# Maximum values of one column based on multiple other columns

Tags: r, max, dummy-variable

this question is quite specific I guess.

I am looking for the R equivalent of Stata egen function, in particular

> egen max BY varlist.

In my data table I have a column with ID

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6)
```

a column with year of observation

```
year <- c(2000,2000,2001,2002,2002,2003,2004,2004,2004)
```

year and ID are not unique, because there can be more observations in one year.

Finally I have a column with names

```
names <- c("Mark",NA,"John","John",NA,"Sarah","Julia",NA,NA).
```

First of all I want to generate a dummy that is equal to 1 if name is not NA and I figured

```
dummy <-  ifelse(!is.na(names),1,0)
```

Then I want R to return the maximum of the dummy based on ID and year, which in Stata would be

```
egen MAX = max(dummy), by(ID year)
```

In practice, I want R to return 0 if names is NA for all rows with the same ID and year. So I would get (1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0) and I can proceed to drop rows 5,7,8.
Thank you!

Comment: thanks but doesn't seem to be working. complete.cases(ID,year,names) returns [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE which is not what I want.

Comment: Do you want `!with(dat, ave(is.na(names), list(ID,year), FUN=all))` or similar? `dat` being `dat <- data.frame(ID,year,names, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: @thelatemail yes perhaps the question wasn't super clear but this returns the right result. I tried to look on help page but I'm not entirely clear on why this works. Would you please explain why we are taking the average with FUN=all? Edit:already answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `ave`, but this logic will work with any grouping function you might know. Look for `NA`s by group, see if they are not (`!`/ `Negate`) `all` `TRUE`:

```
ave(is.na(dat[["names"]]), dat[c("ID","year")], FUN=Negate(all))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID,year,names, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: why not `ave(!is.na(dat[["names"]]), dat[c("ID","year")], FUN=all)`?

Comment: @Onyambu - for sure. Just personal preference, but that will work fine too.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID, year) %>% 
   mutate(dummy = as.integer(any(!is.na(names))))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups: ID, year [7]
#     ID  year names  dummy
#  <dbl> <dbl> <fctr> <int>
#1  1.00  2000 Mark       1
#2  1.00  2000 <NA>       1
#3  2.00  2001 John       1
#4  2.00  2002 John       1
#5  3.00  2002 <NA>       0
#6  4.00  2003 Sarah      1
#7  5.00  2004 Julia      1
#8  6.00  2004 <NA>       0
#9  6.00  2004 <NA>       0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID, year, names)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Stata, but based on your description, this should do the trick:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6),
  year = c(2000,2000,2001,2002,2002,2003,2004,2004,2004),
  names = c("Mark",NA,"John","John",NA,"Sarah","Julia",NA,NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

mydata$dummy <- as.integer(!is.na(mydata$names))

max_dummy <- aggregate(mydata$dummy, mydata[c("ID","year")], max)

has_name <- subset(merge(mydata, max_dummy), x > 0)[-5]

has_name
```